# Whats the correct way of accessing AuthComponent::user in Model in Cakephp

Tags: model, cakephp-2.0

I need to set a varibiale from the AuthComponent

```
var $something = AuthComponent::user('group_id');
```

Gives me a syntax error in NetBeans. If I just set:

```
var $something = AuthComponent::user;
```

I dont get an error, but does this contain all the user data, and how do I then access it for a conditional key value pair?

```
'Group' => array(
            'className' => 'Group',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
            'conditions' => '', // access the Auth Component here
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not set methods to properties of a class, hence the error. The controller is also loaded before the component.

Just use `AuthComponent::user('group_id')` when needed or create a wrapper method for it like `$this->groupId()` which does the Auth call